# CUPS printers does not show up in printer dialog

Tags: macos, printing, cups

If i add a printer through normal print-dialog (preferences->printers) in OSX it shows in the list.

If i then go into CUPS and change the driver for this printer to RAW ( thats what i need ) - then i can do that, but it then dissapears from my print-dialog list.

This creates a problem for me as my application then also cannot see it, i can still see the printer in CUPS though.

Since im not able to create a RAW printer driver for a printer added in the standard printdialog CUPS seems to be the only way that its possible, but just dont understand why CUPS printers are removed from the OSX print-dialog.

Is there any way to get the CUPS printers (all) to be shown in the print-dialog ?

Answer (score 5):

Found out.

After adding/modifying the printer in CUPS you need to "Add Class" for that printer, this will show in the print-dialog.